# OSMC: script running @ 100% cpu on 1 core

Tags: kodi

The following thing has been a thorn in my side on my pi2 osmc install.

This script is running constantly, causing 1 core to be loaded for 100% all the time.

The thing is... when I kill it, kodi/osmc will crash at some point. (Not instantly, just somewhere later in the day or so.)

Anyone that can shed some light on this?

[image: htop]

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in OSMC, you should probably let them know.

Comment: It could be one of the things that got in there while fiddling with it myself, however I'm not sure where to look for this specific script. OSMC doesn't seem to have this script in another PI I have